# Get full file path including file's name from an uploaded file in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I have this web application project which requires a better user-interface and I am doing it by C#.
I already have my html file with JS done but I need some data from user.
In my JS embedded in HTML file, I used the code below to find the file on local driver and get the data from that excel file and then put all these data into an array.

`var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open(file1);
            var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");`

However, the "file1" you see above seems to require a full name path,say "C:\test.xls" in my case. 
I am new to C# and just built a button on my form design, by clicking the button, I seem to be able to browse my local file.

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int size = -1;
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
                string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                size = text.Length;
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file);



        }
        Console.WriteLine(size); // <-- Shows file size in debugging mode.
        Console.WriteLine(result); // <-- For debugging use.
    }
```

So, my question:

How can I get this kind of full file path of an uploaded file in C# ?
And furthermore, it would be awesome if some one can tell me how to get this value into my javascript or HTML!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Internet Explorer has a setting "include full path when uploading local files to a server". Sounds like you can't depend on obtaining that. It's [disabled by default](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919181(v=ws.10).aspx) according to TechNet.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to depend on getting the full path.    In the end, the browser only needs to multi-part encode the physical file and submit it as a form post (of sorts).      So once it has it's location and has encoded it -- it's done using it.

It's considered a security risk to expose the file structure to Javascript/HTML (ie., the internet).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that there will be some risk to expose my file to Internet. However, my application is just a simple one. Will just need to display for a few seconds and I think it won't be a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update.

I used another logic and it worked as expected. Instead of getting absolute file path , I managed to open the file , save it as somewhere and make my html call find that file path no matter what.